# Lowercase and uppercase vice versa

Tags: ios, строки, objective-c

У меня есть предложение, подобное следующему: 
"The NSString class and its mutable subclass, NSMutableString, provide an extensive set of APIs for working with strings, including methods for comparing, searching, and modifying strings. "

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы каждое слово начиналось со строчной буквы и заканчивалось прописной. Подскажите, как лучше всего это реализовать?

Comment: Как вы пытались решить эту задачу?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk добавил решение ниже, решил с помощью блоков, если у вас есть идеи как еще можно, будет только плюс :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи рекомендую создать категорию:

```
@interface NSString (AdditionalMethods)

- (NSString* _Nonnull)withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercased;
- (NSString* _Nonnull)withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercasedForEachWord;

@end
```

Метод `withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercased` делает первую буквы строчной, последнюю - прописной:

```
- (NSString* _Nonnull)withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercased {
    if (self.length == 0) {
        return self;
    }
    NSMutableString* result = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:self];
    [result replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[self substringToIndex:1].lowercaseString];
    [result replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(self.length - 1, 1) withString:[self substringFromIndex:self.length - 1].uppercaseString];
    return result;
}
```

Метод `withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercasedForEachWord` вызывает `withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercased` для каждого слова, а затем производит замену в исходной строке:

```
- (NSString* _Nonnull)withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercasedForEachWord {
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:self];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                          usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [result replaceCharactersInRange:substringRange withString:substring.withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercased];
    }];
    return result;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
NSString* text = @"The NSString class declares the programmatic interface for an object that manages immutable strings. An immutable string is a text string that is defined when it is created and subsequently cannot be changed.";
NSLog(@"%@", text.withFirstCharLowercasedLastCharUppercasedForEachWord); // выводит "thE nSStrinG clasS declareS thE programmatiC interfacE foR aN objecT thaT manageS immutablE stringS. aN immutablE strinG iS A texT strinG thaT iS defineD wheN iT iS createD anD subsequentlY cannoT bE changeD."
```

Comment: @Roman_Podymov ваш вариант будет лучше моего решения, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу с помощью блоков, решение будет описано ниже.

```
NSString* text = @"The NSString class declares the programmatic interface for an object that manages immutable strings. An immutable string is a text string that is defined when it is created and subsequently cannot be changed.";

NSMutableString *lowerUpperString = [text mutableCopy];
[lowerUpperString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[lowerUpperString length])
                            options:(NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {

NSMutableString* disfiguredString = [substring mutableCopy];
                             [disfiguredString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(disfiguredString.length - 1, 1)
                                                            withString:[[disfiguredString substringFromIndex:disfiguredString.length - 1] capitalizedString]];
                             [lowerUpperString replaceCharactersInRange:substringRange
                                                             withString:disfiguredString];
                             *stop = enclosingRange.location + enclosingRange.length == lowerUpperString.length;
                         }];
NSLog(@"%@", lowerUpperString);
```

Получил следующее: ThE NSStrinG clasS declareS thE programmatiC interfacE foR aN objecT thaT manageS immutablE stringS. AN immutablE strinG iS A texT strinG thaT iS defineD wheN iT iS createD anD subsequentlY cannoT bE changeD.

Comment: Разве у Вас в результате не должна получиться строка "thE nSStrinG clasS declareS ..." ?

Comment: ожидал такого результата, нужно поиграть с индексом